# Autocomplete/tagging jQuery plugin with ordering and cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput, textboxlist

> I'm looking for a jQuery tagging/autocomplete plugin where I tags can be inserted mid-order  - and control over this is possible with the mouse.

I've gone through everything I can find, but am yet to find a plugin with all the requirements I'm looking for. I'm looking for a Facebook-esque tagging plugin, yet I'll be working with pre-defined phrases, and building them up into a paragraph, so I need to be able to control the order, and potentially insert a new tag in the middle of an existing selection.

The closest I've found to having this functionality is [TextBoxList](http://www.devthought.com/wp-content/projects/jquery/textboxlist/Demo/) and the 'Facebook Theme' of [JQuery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html). Both of these however only allow you to move the cursor between tags with the arrow keys - and I'm looking to be able to mouseclick to control the cursor aswell.

Anyone know anything that's got what I need? A few other key essentials are free-text input (when no tag matches), remote source of data, and form submission, but I'd hope they'll be easier to retro-fit to something else!

Answer (score 0):

An update for Googlers - I went with jQuery-tokeninput, and have spent the day modifying the library to work with mouse input. When I get time to tidy the code, and check how it works with other themes, I may put a pull request on GitHub, it seems like fairly useful functionality to me.

Comment: Hey chris, Did you able to code for tagging using jquery-tokeninput. I am searching for this functionlity. If you have done that please provide me the code.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean...do you mean for allowing free tags? There's a parameter in the jquery-tokeninput library for that.